# Datagridviewのデータ検索について

Tags: c#

Form1にDatagridviewを表示させ、
Form1の検索メニューを押すと、
Form2ダイアログが開き、検索する名前を入れます。
Form2の検索を押すと、Form1の該当する名前にフォーカスします。

というプログラムを作成したいです。
Form1とForm2間でForm1のDatagridviewのデータ、もしくは、
Form2のtextboxのデータが上手く渡せません。

以下が途中のプログラムです。

Form1

```
namespace datagrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // 3列定義します。
            dt.Columns.Add("PName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            //dt.Columns.Add("C", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));

            // 4行追加します。
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        row["PName"] =　"太郎";
                        row["Age"] = 20;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        row["PName"] = "次郎";
                        row["Age"] = 21;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        row["PName"] = "三郎";
                        row["Age"] = 22;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        row["PName"] = "四郎";
                        row["Age"] = 23;
                        break;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            // DataSetにdtを追加します。
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            dt.TableName = "Table1";
            //datagridviewに表示
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void 検索ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 FS = new Form2();
            if (FS.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
namespace datagrid
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchName = textBox1.Text;
            // PNameの列でserchNameと同じ文字列検索
            for(int i=0; ;i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1とForm2の画面です。ご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

`Form2`に`textbox1.Text`を公開するプロパティを定義して、`検索ToolStripMenuItem_Click`で参照するのが通常の設計だと思います。

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string SearchName
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
    // button1_ClickはDialogResultプロパティを指定すれば不要
}
```

Form1

```
private void 検索ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 FS = new Form2();
    if (FS.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // FS.SearchNameで処理を行う。
    }
}
```

また検索処理の一例としては以下のような形になります。

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var r = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if (object.Equals(((DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem)["PName"], FS.SearchName))
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        r.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```